# Simple differentiability question

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

If $g(x) = ax^3$ for $x \leq 2$ and $b(x-3)^2 + 10$ for $x>2$,
Find the value of $a$ and $b$ such that the $g$ is differentiable at $x=2$

So strictly speaking for this g to be differentiable the limits of the gradient functions either side of 2 must be equal to each other, that was my reasoning, so in the end I got that 
$12a = -2b$ . 
But thats not the answer, as apparently you are supposed to get $\frac{5}{7}$ and $\frac{-30}{7}$ .
The answers satisfy my conditions for $a$ and $b$, but I need help on how to get a second equation of $a$ and $b$ to get to the numerical value answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find values of $a$ and $b$:

For $x \leq 2$:

$$g'(x)=3ax^2$$

For $x > 2$:

$$g'(x)=2b(x-3)^1$$

So:

$$g'(2)=3 a\cdot 2^2=2b(2-3)^1$$

So you must have:

$$12a=-2b$$

But $g$ also must be $\textbf{continuous}$ function, so:

$$ax^3=b(x-3)^2+10$$

For $x=2$, so:

$$a2^3=b(2-3)^2+10$$

By this two equations you should get answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

first you need $g$ to be continuous at $x = 2.$ that requires $$8a = b + 10.$$ now you need the derivatives to match at $x = 2$ and that requires $$12 a = -2b$$

you have two equations for two unknowns $a, b$ and do you know how to solve for them?

Comment: No, please clarify that!